# Does it make sense to add an answer from a Support ticket as an answer of a my own question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763309/why-and-when-twilio-removes-the-error-message-from-the-receiver-service) about Twilio.
As I did not receive any answer in a week I decided to post that question in a support ticket on my Twilio account.

I know, I had to do that before, but the support desk doesn't know to much about some technical stuff of the tool and I found a lot of questions for Twilio that some "Twilio evangelist" answered.

So, my question is that I receive an answer on the Support ticket and I'm not sure if I have to add that answer as my own answer of the question.

Comment: Do you think the answer would be helpful to other people? If so you've probably answered your own question.

Comment: The question doesn't have votes, so I think probably it's not helpful .

Comment: Well based on the tags that you've used, it's not a very visible question. Twilio only has 137 followers. XML has 5.9k, but even so you've only got 24 views, a fair few I would imagine came as a result of this post. I wouldn't read too much into the lack of votes given that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are under no obligations to post any content to Stack Overflow at all, if you don't want to post the answer to your question then that is entirely up to you.

*However*, if the question that you have an answer for (it doesn't matter if you asked it or not) is on-topic, and if you can formulate an answer to it that would read clearly and be useful to others, then we would *absolutely* encourage you to post the answer.

The purpose of Stack Overflow is to build up a repository of knowledge - by posting good answers to questions you help to further that goal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! If you have knowledge which isn't on the SO website and would suit the site, please post it - it may help people in the future.

One caveat though is that you must *make sure you have the permission to post any information you get from a 3rd party resource* (e.g. what you're posting isn't copyrighted, etc). If you do have permission, it's considered polite to attribute the source of the information.